# finding the inclination of the vector that maximizes the norm

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix A = $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $||$A$||_{op}$ = sup$_{||x||=1}$ $||$Ax$||$. We also know that there is a vector v such that $||$Av$||$ = $||$A$||_{op}$.

I want to find the inclination of 'v' w.r.t X-axis. Although -v also works but I want to use the one that lies right of the Y-axis.

I suspect that right singular vector corresponding to smallest singular value. I was wondering if there is an easier or shortcut way to do this.

Comment: What is the norm on the space? I suspect Euclidean?

Comment: yes it is Euclidean Norm

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\| Av\|^2 = v^T A^T A v = v^T \left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{matrix} \right) v
.$$
$\lambda=(3+\sqrt{5})/2$ is the largest eigenvalue so $\|A\|=\sqrt{\lambda} = (1+\sqrt{5})/2=:\gamma$. The corresponding eigenvector $(1,\gamma)^T$ from which you may calculate the angle with the $X$ axis. Not sure I understand what you are getting at regarding the smallest sing value?